# Adding a nested element to a "flat" list

Tags: list, nested, tcl

I have a "flat" Tcl list. Now I want to append a new element as a child to one of the existing elements. How can I do this?

This is what I tried:

```
[ lindex $flights $i ] [ lindex $flight 0 ] ]
```

I try to add an element form the list "flight" to an element of the list "flights". The element `$i` in the flights list already exists.

I might be running against `Tcl` syntax as I'm new to `Tcl`.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **lset** to replace an element of your list with a new list. http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/lset.htm The first element of the new list will be the old element, the 2nd element will be its child. Here's an example:

```
% set flights [list a b c d e]
a b c d e
% set i 1
1
% lset flights $i [list b child]
a {b child} c d e
% lindex $flights 1
b child
% lindex [lindex $flights 1] 1
child
% lindex [lindex $flights 1] 0
b
```

Comment: Also: `lindex $flights 1 0` is useful, and in 8.6 you can use `lset flights $i end+1 child`. (Doesn't work in 8.5, which won't let `lset` extend lists.)

Comment: Thanks, I missed the list keyword.